# Change code for Console output to JSON output

Tags: javascript, c#, json, debugging, console.writeline

I have a code to read a QAAWS and prints it out to the console, what I want to do now is to instead create a javascript that will run the same code but will save it as a JSON that can be used by a website. I tried to do `Debug.WriteLine()` instead of `Console.WriteLine()` which it has not worked.

I have writen code before to read an XML and convert it to a JSON but somehow this is giving me more issue. Here is the code to read it in the console:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using ConsoleApp1.TestWeb;

namespace ConsoleApp1 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            ConsoleApp1.TestWeb.QAAWS_by_USER test1 = new
            ConsoleApp1.TestWeb.QAAWS_by_USER();
            String message, creatorname, creationdateformatted, description, universe;
            DateTime creationdate;
            int queryruntime, fetchedrows;
            ConsoleApp1.TestWeb.Row[] row = test1.runQueryAsAService("<username>", "<password>", out message, out creatorname, out creationdate, out creationdateformatted, out description, out universe, out queryruntime, out fetchedrows);
            int resultCount = row.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < resultCount; i++) {
                Console.WriteLine(row[i].User + " " + row[i].Owed);
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if there is any other information you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We used QAAWS at work, so here is an approach you can use. Instead of using a console application better create an asmx Web service. The service will contain a class that will return an ArrayList and the asmx file will take the list and return the JSON. Here is how it would look

`TestWebService.asmx.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace TestWebService {
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for TestService
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class TestService : System.Web.Services.WebService {

        private LoadService user;

        public TestService() {
            this.user = new LoadService();
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public string TestResult() {
            ArrayList list = this.user.getTestUser();

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the `TestWebService.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace TestWebService {
    public class LoadService {
        public ArrayList getTestUser() {
            TestWebService.TestWeb.QAAWS_by_USER test1 = new
            TestWebService.TestWeb.QAAWS_by_USER();
            String message, creatorname, creationdateformatted, description, universe;
            DateTime creationdate;
            int queryruntime, fetchedrows;
            TestWebService.TestWeb.Row[] row = test1.runQueryAsAService(("<username>", "<password>", out message, out creatorname, out creationdate, out creationdateformatted, out description, out universe, out queryruntime, out fetchedrows);
            int resultCount = row.Length;
            var index = 0;
            var list = new ArrayList();
            for (int i = 0; i < resultCount; i++) {
                getUserInformation userInformation = new getUserInformation {
                    User_name = row[i].User,
                    Owed_value = row[i].Owed
                };
                list.Add(userInformation);
                index++;
            }
            return list;
        }
    }
    public class getUserInformation {
        public string User_name { get; set; }
        public double Owed_value { get; set; }
    }
}
```